# symbolic link in solr

Tags: solr, symlink, solr-schema

what is symbolic link in solr. Is there any concept exist in solr related to schema..?
Is it related creation of class object specified in schema.xml..                                                                                                                                                                                                 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symbolic link is a concept in computing not in Solr.

> In computing, a [symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) (also symlink or soft link) is a special
>   type of file that contains a reference to another file or directory in
>   the form of an absolute or relative path and that affects pathname
>   resolution.

One of the exaple when you need symbolic link is, if you install solr using package manager then it installs default configuration files (schema.xml , solrconfig.xml). So, you need to replace this default configurations with yours by creating a symbolic link.

[Check this post](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/solr-setup.html), it could give you an idea.